# ¿Cuando usar call, check_output ,run, Popen en python con la librería subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x

Se me presenta una duda con estas funcionalidades del subprocess, ya que para ejecutar un comando, usan estas diferentes formas que mencione en el titulo de la pregunta (en muchos scripts de github se ve que usan para llamar un comando cualquiera de estos, pero debe haber diferencias me imagino), hay algo en especial que deba tener en cuenta a la hora de elegir una para pasar un comando por la shell?

Ademas subprocess permite ejecutar un comando o guardar la salida de este.

Es acaso esta la razon de usar alguno de los que mencione, para llevar a ?

Muchas gracias.